# Double surname abbreviated in citations only

Tags: biblatex, authoryear

In my bibliography I have an author with a double surname (say, Pata Kata).
When I cite this author in the text, it appears as (Pata Kata <year>), but I would like it to appear as (P. Kata <year>) in the citation only (that is, in the bibliography list, I still want it to be printed as "Pata Kata, F.", where "F" is the author's first-name initial). Manually changing the author field to

> author = {P. Kata, Firstname}

in the bib entry, would also change how the author appears in the bibliography list. So this is not a solution. I tried to use the `\relax` command in the authors field, like so:

> author = {{\relax{}P}ata} Kata, Firstname}

but it doesn't work. The citation is still printed as (Pata Kata <year>).

In case it matters, in my bibliography I also have an author with a single surname, which coincides with the first author's second surname (Kata). This author should be cited as (Kata <year>).

Something important is that I need a solution for the biber backend. I do not want to have to change to bibtex, because it does not provide biber's flexibilities and I already use quite a few biber features.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,uniquelist=minyear,style=authoryear-comp,
            giveninits=true,uniquename=init]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{papers.bib}
 @INPROCEEDINGS{ref1,
    author = {{\relax{}P}ata Kata, Firstname},
    title = {The title of Pata Kata's article},
    year = {1997},
    booktitle= {The Proceedings of this conference}
}
@INPROCEEDINGS{ref2,
    author = {Kata, Anotherfirstname},
    title = {Another title},
    year = {2000},
    booktitle= {The Proceedings of that conference}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{papers.bib}

\begin{document}
First citation is~\parencite{ref1} and second is~\parencite{ref2}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try `shortauthor = {P. Kata, Firstname},` in `papers.bib`.

Comment: @hair-splitter why don't you turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @hair-splitter Thanks, this works! I was also going to suggest you to turn this into an answer. For a more complete answer, in case Pata Kata appears in multi-authored work, where his name is first, then `shortauthor = {P. Kata, Firstname and Other, Author}` also works, so that the citation appears as (P. Kata et al. <year>).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the following to the bib file:
`shortauthor = {P. Kata, Firstname},`
i.e.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,uniquelist=minyear,style=authoryear-comp,
            giveninits=true,uniquename=init]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{papers.bib}
 @INPROCEEDINGS{ref1,
    author = {Pata Kata, Firstname},
    shortauthor = {P. Kata, Firstname},
    title = {The title of Pata Kata's article},
    year = {1997},
    booktitle= {The Proceedings of this conference}
}
@INPROCEEDINGS{ref2,
    author = {Kata, Anotherfirstname},
    title = {Another title},
    year = {2000},
    booktitle= {The Proceedings of that conference}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{papers.bib}

\begin{document}
First citation is~\parencite{ref1} and second is~\parencite{ref2}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```